# How can a volume exist on more than one physical disk?

Tags: delphi, disk, ioctl

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_volume_get_volume_disk_extents) they say that calling `DeviceIoControl` with `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` control code, "*retrieves the physical location of a specified volume on one or more disks.*" But from my 25 years of using compuers I know that a physical disk can have one or more volumes, not the other way around. I can't even imagine how a volume can exist on multiple physical disks. So, the question is, which are the cases when a volume exists on multiple disks?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  It's been possible for years in Windows to have a volume which spans multiple physical disks.  See the [Dynamic Disks section here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spanned Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vds/volume-object)

> A spanned volume combines areas of unallocated space from multiple disks into one logical volume, allowing you to more efficiently use all of the space and all the drive letters on a multiple-disk system.

Though it's only supported on [dynamic disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks#basic-and-dynamic-disks)

> The following operations can be performed only on dynamic disks:
>   ...
>   Extend a simple or spanned volume.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks explains what you must at least have heard of in your 25 years: (software) RAIDs. A RAID 0 is basically your solution to the problem "*no disk exists that is large enough for my needs*".